# Searching for an old SF short story that features a plot twist involving white genocide

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

It is a short story, included in a collection, that I read a long while ago (at least 10 years ago). Set in Central(?) Africa and features some sort of lake/dam super building/engineering project.

Reference is made to an apocalyptic war/trauma event throughout the story, but it is only at the end of the story that it is revealed that the event concluded with what amounted to white genocide.

I'm looking for the title, author, and if possible what collection/s it appeared in (or any of the above).

Comment: I recognize this story but I can't remember the author or title. It is definitely by a well-known British writer and I seem to associate it with the name Brian Aldiss. Perhaps someone else can take it from there.

Comment: There's and Arthur C Clarke Short story called Reunion, which finishes with the final line "If any of you are still white, we can cure you."  It's not this story is it?  Not quite white genocide, but it's what I thought of.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This story is "[There is a Tide](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56895)" by Brian Aldiss, first published in [*New Worlds Science Fiction* #44, February 1956](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?59639+c), which is available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/New_Worlds_044v15_1956-02#page/n81/mode/2up).

> I seemed to know what was coming as I stood in the crowded room, knowing Jubal dead, knowing the nation of Africa to be bleeding to death. We were dying of our own wounds. The ten years to follow would be as terrible as the ten years of the Massacre, when every member of the white race had been slain.
> Now we Negroes, in our turn, stood at the bar of history.

Comment: Many thanks! Thats the one I was looking for.

Comment: I remember reading that story from "Space, Time and Nathaniel" and I do think the text is as given. The text in the scanned issue of "New Worlds" is not like that. It reads there: _"The ten years to follow would be as terrible as the ten years of the Plague, when every member of the white races had died from its virulence. Now we negroes, in our turn, stood at the bar of history"_. Taking the sting out but confusingly leaving the "bar of history" there, while no-one can be accused of anything by said bar.

Comment: Confirming that "Massacre" is the word used in the collection _"Space, Time and Nathaniel"_ ([NEL edition, 4th printing, September 1974](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?109361)) but that word being used _in lieu_ throughout in "New Worlds" is "Plague". Still, the publication in "New Worlds" is the first one, 1956. I don't know what to make of this.