# Short story with a first person narrator in a future where racial conflict had exploded into an all out war

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Years ago, I read a story with a first person narrator that dealt with a future in which racial conflict had exploded into an all out war. At the end of the story the identity of the narrator is revealed: throughout the story he seems to be a white man, but in the end he is black.

I don't remember much more of it, save for the fact that the character is walking through some form of underground, and that the story is set in the United States. The conflict seemed to be a gang war kind of thing, with regular weaponry. I read the story in the late 1990s, early 2000s, but it was not new, it was in an anthology I found in my school library.

It's not Aldiss's "There is a Tide". It had more of a 1980s feel to it.

Answer (score 12):

I suspect you're looking for "[There is a Tide](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56895)" by Brian Aldiss, as per [Searching for an old SF short story that features a plot twist involving white genocide](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/116195/searching-for-an-old-sf-short-story-that-features-a-plot-twist-involving-white-g?rq=1). As noted in that answer, it's [available in the Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/New_Worlds_044v15_1956-02#page/n81/mode/2up) to read.

> I seemed to know what was coming as I stood in the crowded room, knowing Jubal dead, knowing the nation of Africa to be bleeding to death. We were dying of our own wounds. The ten years to follow would be as terrible as the ten years of the Massacre, when every member of the white race had been slain.
> Now we Negroes, in our turn, stood at the bar of history.

I thought I remembered this one coming up before, and I found it with a Google search for `site:scifi.stackexchange.com story-identification war genocide black`.

Comment: If this is the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the story I'm looking for. The one I'm after takes place in the US.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like Wilson Tucker's "The Year of the Quiet Sun" to me. Does the name Brian Chaney sound familiar? Ramjets?

Comment: I thought of that too, but the OP is looking for a short story, and also it's not a secret in TYOTQS that the protagonist is black.

Comment: @OrganicMarble - nope. Throughout the book the race of the protagonist is mentioned only in the end. I agree with the answer. I have not encountered any book with such similar plot, It is "the year of the quiet sun"

Answer (score 1):

Could this be "American Dead" by Harry Harrison, in the anthology "The Year 2000" (1970)?

There is a full-on race war taking place in America. The protagonist "Bruno" is some kind of ?reporter?, watching a guerilla action by blacks against white troops commanded by a man called "Mau Mau". However I don't recall a reveal of his colour. There are a number of other race conflict stories in that anthology.